# Trouble installing new SSL certificate (Apache2 Virtual Host)

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, virtualhost, port

I'm having trouble trying to install a new SSL certificate for Apache2. We have regular traffic running on port 80, SSL running on 443.

I modified *httpd.conf*, only renaming `/etc/httpd/conf/2009certs/` to `/etc/httpd/conf/2010certs/`:

```
<VirtualHost ServerIP:443>
  # This parameter already existed as-is
  SSLEngine on

  # These are the parameters I changed (already existed w/ diff paths.)
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/2010certs/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/2010certs/server.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/2010certs/intermediate.pem
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/2010certs/gs_root.pem

  # Other parameters here; ServerAdmin, DocumentRoot, ServerName, ErrorLog, etc....
</VirtualHost>
```

Another VirtualHost block exists for `*:80`, but no changes were made to that area.

After saving *httpd.conf* with the new cert paths, commenting out the old 2009 paths, and attempting to restart apache, I get the following in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` and `httpd` fails to start:

> You configured HTTP(80) on the
>   standard HTTPS(443) port!

Nothing was changed except the certificate paths, and te issue disappears after changing *httpd.conf* back to use the old certificates.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried putting the DNS name into the VirtualHost declaration? Example: <VirtualHost my.secure.site:443>

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this with no success; the same problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up being due to the presence of a pass phrase on the RSA private key-file *server.key* -- the apache start scripts were not configured to provide one.

I'm not quite sure why this resulted in the error message above. I'm guessing that apache fell back to a different VirtualHost configuration on port 80 when it failed to read the SSL private key file and couldn't start as HTTPS on 443.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, but the problem turned out to be a missing "ServerName" directive in the  section. I suggest trying this modification to your configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost ServerIP:443>

  ServerName   host.domain

  # This parameter already existed as-is
  SSLEngine on

  # These are the parameters I changed (already existed w/ diff paths.)
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/2010certs/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/2010certs/server.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/2010certs/intermediate.pem
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/2010certs/gs_root.pem

  # Other parameters here; ServerAdmin, DocumentRoot, ServerName, ErrorLog, etc....
</VirtualHost>
```

The third line:    `Servername  host.domain` should be added and `server.domain` should be replaced with the actual hostname and domain of your web site.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but the cause was that the domain of one of the virtual hosts resolved to an IP of a different server.